# OGR VRT MSSQL example

Tags: ogr, sql-server, saga

I'm trying to import vector data into SAGA GIS from a SQLExpress 2008 server.
Firstly is this possible?

I would have thought using an OGR VRT layer would have been the way to do it, I've attached a sample of my vrt file, any help would be great.

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
<OGRVRTLayer name="tempGeom">
    <SrcDataSource>MSSQL:server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=test;trusted_connection=yes</SrcDataSource> 
    <SrcSQL>select *, geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (' + CAST(x AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(z AS VARCHAR) +' '+ CAST(y AS VARCHAR) +')',0) as geom  from dbo.testTable</SrcSQL>
</OGRVRTLayer>
```

Comment: are you sure that SrcDataSource string is correct.  I have never seen (local) in a connection string before, I normally use localhost\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I've tried localhost and pc name no luck.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? I have a similar issue - I have defined a OGR VRT layer that points to SQL Server 2008, and which ogrinfo verifies as ok, but mapnik reports as "unable to open datasource".